# Compare data cells from two independent file

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I would like to compare the cells values from two different Excel files.

I have already done a program which is working if it's on the same sheet. Now, I would like to "external" the first cell.
The program should compare each line of one column to the other spreadsheet

```
Sub Update_production()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, refmiss As Integer, comments As String
    i = 5
    j = 15
    refmiss = 0

    Do while '[Production pallet.xlsx]September'!$A$i.Value <> ""          

        Do While Cells(j, 1).Value <> ""
            If (Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(j, 1).Value) Then
                j = j + 1
            Else
                Cells(j, 3).Value = Cells(j, 3).Value + Cells(i, 3).Value
                Cells(j, 4).Value = Cells(j, 4).Value + Cells(i, 4).Value
                j = j + 1
                refmiss = 1
            End If
        Loop
        If (refmiss = 0) Then
            comments = Cells(i, 1).Value
            Range("A15").Select
            ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = comments
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
        End If
        refmiss = 0
        i = i + 1
        j = 15
    Loop
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help (if it's possible to keep the do while, it could be really nice because I don't know how many line it will be in the both spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [application.worbook.open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819(v=office.15).aspx) method.

```
Sub Openfilemacro()
Dim myfile As String

myfile = "Path\to\file"

Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfile

End Sub
```

Then you can reference between workbooks for comparing, just specify the WB and WS, like you have already.

Something like this, but adapted for you -

```
Sub Openfilemacro()
Dim myfile As String
Dim workbookA As Workbook
Dim workbookB As Workbook
myfile = "Path\to\file"
workbookA = ThisWorkbook
workbookB = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myfile)

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Workbooks(workbookA).Range("A:A")
    If c = "" Then Exit Sub
        'search workbookB for c.value
        'do stuff

Next

End Sub
```

A quick note - you probably want to avoid using the `.select` and `activecell` properties as it can become messy. Try to always reference the actual cell, and there's no need to ever select a cell. Maybe you'll need a `workbook.activate`, but in general, it's less than desirable to need to select anything or reference an active cell, especially with a `for loop` already.